# git review -s Problems encountered installing commit-msg hook

Tags: windows, git, hook, git-bash, msg

Every time I use `git review -s` or `git review` in general I get this :

```
klanten-pers (master)
$ git review -s
Problems encountered installing commit-msg hook
The following command failed with exit code 255
scp -P29418 gido.ten.cate@ci.indicia.nl:hooks/commit-msg .git/hooks/commit-msg

0 [main] scp 1628 C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\scp.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x400000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487
614 [main] scp 1628 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to scp.exe.stackdump
0 [main] scp 5896 fork: child -1 - forked process 1628 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I searched the internet and tried everything I could of but I cant fix it.

I am on Windows 10 using Git bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## * important link  *

Follow these steps to make it work again:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/Alternatives_to_git-review

I fixed the problem.
I needed to add msg-hook to the git folder again.
So in my case it was :

- *C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\share\git-core\templates\hooks*

and after you add it you need to give it the permissions to be executeable.
You can also do it into de specific repository in question.
but then it would be :

- *-- repository/.git/hooks*

Some other Git review -s problems and solutions
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Talk:Gerrit/Tutorial